# Set new `path` value for ImageField

Tags: python, django, django-1.3

I have the following situation. Project files was stored in ~/django-apps/app-old/app. For some reasons I move files to ~/django-apps/app . Application have some images, stored with use of ImageField. In database images have paths like so:

`~/django-apps/app-old/app/media/images/blabla.jpeg`

So, I need to fix this paths in database to look like this:

`~django-apps/app/media/images/blabla.jpeg`

I try to write management command for to do this:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from books.models import Book
import string

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = ''

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        books = Book.objects.all()
        total = len(books)
        curr = 1

        for book in books:
            print "%d/%d" % (curr, total)
            if book.cover_url != "":
                book.cover_url.path = string.replace(book.cover_url.path, "app-old/", "")
                book.save()
            curr+=1
```

By using this command I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/var/www/dizpers/data/django-apps/app/books/management/commands/fix-covers-path.py", line 23, in handle
    book.cover_url.path = string.replace(book.cover_url.path, "bparser-old/", "")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 65, in _get_path
    return self.storage.path(self.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 234, in path
    raise SuspiciousOperation("Attempted access to '%s' denied." % name)
django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousOperation: Attempted access to '/var/www/dizpers/data/django-apps/app-old/app/media/covers/a3d9545d3a17bb68a91749019c95357d.jpeg' denied.
```

Why I get this error message? How I can fix image's path?

**UPD1**

My model contain ImageField like this:

```
cover_url = models.ImageField(upload_to=os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, "covers"), null=True, default=None)
```

**UPD2**

[Path property is readonly](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15590)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
for book in books:
        print "%d/%d" % (curr, total)
        if book.cover_url != "":
            new_path = string.replace(book.cover_url.path, "app-old/", "")
            book.cover_url = new_path
            book.save()
        curr+=1
```

Comment: The error like the one in my question. `SuspiciousOperation: Attempted access to '/var/www/dizpers/data/django-apps/app-old/app/media/covers/a3d9545d3a17bb68a91749019c95357d.jpeg' denied.`

Answer (score 1):

You get this message because the default file system storage prevents usage of absolute path for security reasons.

### If you really want to use an absolute path

[django-documents](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-documents/blob/master/documents/models.py) forces absolute paths for security reasons, this is how:

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage


fs = FileSystemStorage(location=UPLOAD_TO)


class Document(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(storage=fs, upload_to=UPLOAD_TO)
```

Where UPLOAD_TO can be an absolute path.

-- UPDATE IN REPLY TO QUESTION UPDATE --

### If you don't need such security

Then you should read the [documentation on FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield):

> FileField.upload_to
>   A local filesystem path that will be appended to your MEDIA_ROOT setting to determine the value of the url attribute.

In your case, `upload_to='covers'` is sufficient.

Note that relative paths should be stored in the database.

Comment: I added to the question update - description of my ImageField. I use there absolute path? I shouldn't do it?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is an ImageField, because ImageField inherits from FileField :) Try it and you'll see ;)

Comment: so, I need to modify my model? and yes, you are right that ImageField inerits from FileField. I speak about absolute path in this field instead of relative - maybe I should use relative path in my ImageField and maybe it will solve the problem?

Comment: I have one question about your updated answer. What kind of security problems I can face, when simply modify model to use relative path (the second way "If you don't need such security")?

Comment: If MEDIA_ROOT is public, then files uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT are public. This is good for example for avatars and such, but not for confidential documents.